# Specific programs crash when the computer is locked?

Tags: windows, lock, background

Due to a new policy, our GPO now locks every computer after 1 hour of being unattended. We have one specific computer which runs testing software that takes a long time, so we typically run it after hours. However, ever since the new GPO, the software will crash after hours. I looked in the logs and it seems to be crashing exactly one hour after the operator clocks out.

From my understanding, everything should keep running in the background while the computer is locked, however, it seems like the lock is causing this specific program to fail. Is there any way to verify that this is causing the crash or troubleshoot?

This is on Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: Why doesn't the system administrator just not move this single computer into it's own OU and disable the offending policy for the single machine.

Comment: Security reasons, we can't have this computer open and accessible for other staff

Comment: As a work-around, you might try an app like Don't Sleep, https://www.softwareok.com/?seite=Microsoft/DontSleep, which will keep the PC running, though locked. Would that violate security requirements?

Comment: It seems there's several obvious things you should be trying, both to test, and to fix. First, to test: does locking the computer manually cause the crash? Have you talked to the developer of this software to report it crashes after a lock? To fix, can you force a sign out on this computer instead of a lock?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik This seems like the best solution, thanks for letting me know of this software